# Where can I obtain a raw YUV File?

Tags: yuv

I need a raw YUV file for research purposes.  Neither the size nor the content is critical.  Any ideas on where such files exist?

Comment: For examle: [YUV Video Sequences](http://trace.eas.asu.edu/yuv/)

Comment: Check here: http://media.xiph.org/video/derf/

Answer (score 11):

You can find all kinds of YUV files with different formats: [here](http://www.sunrayimage.com/examples.html).

Comment: Link broken unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) to convert any other video type to raw YUV. Your source could be from a DVD home movie, for instance, or perhaps a digital video camera.

Comment: Thanks Zach and Joe.  Very good answers.

Answer (score 3):

HI try this link

http://trace.eas.asu.edu/yuv/

I also have some YUV files but there is no option to upload.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert anything to YUV using mencoder:

mencoder.exe -of rawvideo clock.avi -o clock.yuv -nosound -ovc raw

You may add -vf swapuv to swap the U and V components if the colrs aren't correct.