# How to get the HEVC test video sequences?

Tags: hevc, video-compression

I need the HEVC test video sequences, namely Traffic, PeopleOnStreet, Nebuta, SteamLocomotive, Kimono, ParkScene, Cactus, BasketBallDrive etc mentioned in Common Conditions and Software Reference Configuration’s document JCT-VCL1100. I need these video sequences for benchmarking and research purposes.

Comment: What are you asking this here for? Requests for us to find off site resources for you are explicitly off topic.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I asked this because I was asked by a reviewer of a journal to test my algorithm using the above mentioned video sequences. But, I agree that my question should have been reframed as "Are we allowed to use the HEVC test sequences for academic research purposes?"

Comment: that would also not be an acceptable question here; if you want to know that, find and read their license.

Comment: @S.Kahu -- have you located the sequences?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the common sequences are from Xiph. You can find it [here](http://media.xiph.org/video/derf/). Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644501/where-can-i-obtain-a-raw-yuv-file) question for more details.